# Getting incorrect creation dates using 'aws s3'

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cli

I have two buckets. In the AWS Console they have the following "Date created"

```
2017-11-22 14:07:03 i-repo
2018-01-12 17:16:31 l-repo
```

Using the AWS CLI (aws-cli/1.16.90 Python/3.7.2 Darwin/17.7.0 botocore/1.12.80) command `aws s3 ls`, I get the following:

```
2018-02-08 12:49:03 i-repo
2018-12-19 15:55:29 l-repo
```

Using the AWS CLI command `aws s3api list-buckets`, I get the same incorrect dates. I have confirmed that the dates that the AWS CLI reports relate to the date of the most recent bucket policy change, NOT the bucket create date. Am I missing something, or is this a bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like this is a known issue/intended. See below:

> After further investigation and discussion with the S3 team, I have found that this is expected behavior due to the design of the service. The GET Service call in S3 (s3api list-buckets or s3 ls with no further arguments in the CLI) works differently when being run against different regions. All bucket creations are mastered in us-east-1, then replicated on a global scale - the resulting difference is that there are no "replication" events to the us-east-1 region. The Date Created field displayed in the web console is according to the actual creation date registered in us-east-1, while the AWS CLI and SDKs will display the creation date depending on the specified region (or the default region set in your configuration).
>
> When using an endpoint other than us-east-1, the CreationDate you receive is actually the last modified time according to the bucket's last replication time in this region. This date can change when making changes to your bucket, such as editing its bucket policy. This experienced behavior is result of how S3's architecture has been designed and implemented, making it difficult to change without affecting customers that already expect this behavior.
>
> S3 does intend to change this behavior so that the actual bucket creation date is shown regardless of the region in which the GET Service call is issued, however to answer your question we do not yet have an ETA for the implementation of this change. This change would most likely be announced in the AWS Forums for S3 if you'd like to know when it takes place.

[Source](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/3597)

Comment: I was using region eu-west-1